# POST http://localhost:5173/register 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, http-status-code-404

I am doing a CRUD in Raact(created by Vite and using a proxy) with mongodb, express and nodejs with context api (MERN STACK), when I want to make the "POST" request to the /register route from the backend it works but when I do it from the frontend it throws me the error "404 "NOT FOUND", check my code many times and try the error, try to catch it but didn't find the error, here my code.

proxy's config from vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/posts': "http://localhost:3000"  // THIS IS BACKEND'S URL,  THE FRONTEND'S URL IS FROM -> http://localhost:5173
    }
  },
  plugins: [react()]
})
```

FrontEnd's code: ReactJs

Postcontext.jsx

```
import React, { useContext,createContext} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const postContext = createContext()

export const usePost = function(){
const context = useContext(postContext)
return context
}
export const PostProvider = function({children}) {  
const registrarUsuario = async (userRegister) =\> {
const register = await axios.post("http://localhost:5173/register", userRegister)  
console.log(register)
}
return \<postContext.Provider value={{
registrarUsuario
}}\>
{children}
\</postContext.Provider\>
```

Register.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import * as Yup from 'yup'
import { Formik,Form,Field, ErrorMessage } from 'formik'
import toast from 'react-hot-toast'
import { AiOutlineSave } from "react-icons/ai"
import {usePost} from '../context/Postcontext'

function Register() {
   
    const {registrarUsuario} = usePost()
  return (
    <div className='contenedor-formulario'>
        <Formik 
        initialValues={{name: "", email: "", password: ""}} 
        validationSchema={Yup.object({
            nombre: Yup.string().required("name is required").max(30),
            correo: Yup.string().email().required("email is required"),
            contraseña: Yup.string().required("password is required ").max(30)
        })}
        onSubmit={async (values, actions)=>{
                //console.log(values)
                await registrarUsuario(values)  
                actions.setSubmitting(false)
            }}>
        
        
        {({handleSubmit, isSubmitting})=>(
                <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label>Name</label>
                <Field className="campo" name="name" placeholder="name" />
                <ErrorMessage component="p" className='alert' name='name'/>

                <label>Email</label>
                <Field className="campo" name="email" placeholder="email"/>
                <ErrorMessage component="p" className='alert' name='email'/>

                <label>Password</label>
                <Field className="campo" name="password" placeholder="password"/>
                <ErrorMessage component="p" className='alert' name='password'/>


                <button className='save-button' type='submit' disabled={isSubmitting}>{isSubmitting ? (<AiOutlineSave className='animate-bounce'/>) : "save"}</button>
                
            </Form>)}
        </Formik>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Register
```

BackEnd's Code: Node Js , Express:

auth.routes.js

```
import {Router} from 'express'
import {register} from '../controllers/auth.controller.js'

export const routerUser = Router()

routerUser.post('/register', registrar)
routerUser.post('/login', login)
routerUser.get('/users', users)
routerUser.get('/user/:id', user)
```

auth.controller.js

```
import {user} from '../models/usuario.js'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import config from "../src/config.js";
import { role } from '../models/roles.js';


export const register = async (req, res) => {
    const {name, email, password, rol} = req.body
    
    
    const userRegister = new usuario({ 
        name, 
        email,
        password: await user.encryptPassword(password),
        posts: []
    })

    if(rol) {
        const admin = await role.find({nameRol: {$in: roles}})
        registro.roles = admin.map(id => id._id)
    } else{ 
        const user = await role.findOne({nameRol: "user"})
        register.roles = user._id 
    }

    const users = await user.findOne({correo})  
    if (users) return res.status(400).send("already email exists") //this verify email and see if the email exists for then throw errors
    

   

    const user_Saved = await userRegister.save()
    res.json(user_Saved )



}
```

user's and role's model from mongoDB:

model role :

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";

const rol = new Schema({
    nombreRol: String
})

export const role = model("Role", rol)
```

model user:

```
import {Schema, model} from 'mongoose'
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'

const users = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: Boolean,
        unique: Boolean
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: Boolean,
        unique: Boolean
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: Boolean,
        unique: Boolean
    },
    rol: [{
        ref: "Role",
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId 
    }],
    posts: [{
        ref: "Posts",
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId 
    }]
}, )

users.statics.encrpytPassword= async (password) => {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
    return await bcrypt.hash(password, salt)
}  

users.statics.comparePassword= async (password, newPassword) => {
    return await bcrypt.compare(password, newPassword)
}

export const user = model("Users", users)
```

i tried get post at path  /register but this throw a 404's error

```
xhr.js:247          POST http://localhost:5173/register 404 (Not Found)
Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm()
```

Comment: Are the other routes working? How you use the routes in your server config?

Comment: Well that was the same error, I didn't add the paths of /register, /login, /users to the proxy and that's why it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Since you're creating a proxy to `/posts`, your frontend can only send requests to `/posts`. It also doesn't need to reference itself in the `.post` request.

Since you're using `/register`, I would proxy that path as well:

```
proxy: { 
  '/posts': "http://localhost:3000",
  '/register': "http://localhost:3000"
}
```

Then instead of this:

`const register = await axios.post("http://localhost:5173/register", userRegister)`

Just use this:

`const register = await axios.post("/register", userRegister)`

Comment: I used the /posts route because as I said, I'm making a crud of posts like, so since I can already make posts now I want to do a user registration and login and that's why I tried to use the /register in this case to register users, Another one is /login to log in, but when I see that proxy problem, can I place another proxy for those routes?

Comment: Yes, you can proxy multiple endpoints. React will find 404 on an endpoint otherwise. Updated the example. Another way of handling this is having one proxy for `/api/*` which would cover `/api/posts`, `/api/register`, and `/api/login`, etc. Then you reference it as `axios.post("/api/register", ...)` etc.

Comment: and why use /api/*? I have always seen others who use it on their routes but I don't know what it is for or just convenience?

Comment: Yep, mostly for convenience.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to solve this problem :)